# SQL case expression to create a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am currently using Microsoft SQL Server. I am trying to work with case expressions within my view to create a range.

Here is an example:

- The range minimum cannot be below 0.
- The range maximum cannot be above 100.
- Expected output IE: `22.67-88.23`.

Here is what I attempted.

```
CONVERT(varchar(12)
       ,(CASE WHEN (X.AVG - (2 * X.AVG)) < 0
          THEN 0
          END
         + '-'
         + CASE WHEN (X.AVG + (2 * X.AVG)) > 100
           THEN 100
           END
        )) as Range
```

Comment: Case expressions, not statements.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for the tip. I have adjusted my question.

Comment: What is the "issue on the as portion"?

Comment: incorrect syntax near 'as'.

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis at the end. To be honest you have a lot of unnecessary parenthesis in there.

Comment: I have adjusted the parenthesis issue, however I am still not obtaining the string. It ends up being a 'NULL'.

Comment: That's because  the `ELSE` part is missing in your case expressions

Comment: To make things easier: 
X.AVG - (2 * X.AVG) < 0 is equivalent to -X.AVG < 0 is equivalent to X.AVG > 0, 
X.AVG + (2 * X.AVG)) > 100 is equivalent to 3*X.AVG > 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of the missing parenthesis you have since edited in, you also need to include an `else` clause, as your version doesn't return a value if your calculation is above `0` in the first `case` or below `100` in your second one:

```
CONVERT(varchar(12)
       ,(CASE WHEN (X.AVG - (2 * X.AVG)) < 0
          THEN 0
          ELSE X.AVG - (2 * X.AVG)
          END
         + '-'
         + CASE WHEN (X.AVG + (2 * X.AVG)) > 100
           THEN 100
           ELSE X.AVG - (2 * X.AVG)
           END
        )
       ) as Range
```

Comment: I seem to be achieving a 'Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric with you answer. This is because of calculations on a varchar. I adjusted the CONVERT to both the 'Then' & 'Else' in each case expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can massively simplify this entire case expression to this. It may be what you actually want as it seems to contradict your written explanation but it logically is the same thing you have coded.

```
case 
    when X.AVG * 3 > 100 then '100'
    when X.AVG > 0 then '0'
    else 'Invalid' --Or maybe you want to put convert(varchar(12), X.AVG) here?
end
```